# How to upload videos to iPhone and iPad using any Mac or Macbook that I have? (not tied to one Mac)

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipad, video

It seems that nowadays, the only time I hook up my iPad or iPhone to a computer is when I need to upload some videos to the Video app on iPad/iPhone so that I can view them offline.

I started uploaded some videos using a 256GB Macbook Air to the iPad and iPhone (both of which has 128GB).  Next time, because the Macbook Air has only about 1GB disk space left, I tried to use my Macbook Pro to upload the video, but it couldn't -- when I drag the video to the "Device" section on iTunes, the video icon will bounce back to the Finder window -- it seems that I could only use the Macbook Air to transfer because somehow, it is "tied to that iPad/iPhone".

My question is, can I actually upload videos to any iPad/iPhone I have, using any Mac that I have?  I have Macbook Air, Macbook Pro, and Mac Mini.  And it will be best to no need to store the video files on the Macbook Air, for example, say if my Macbook Air only has 1GB of hard drive space left, and at home, I transfer a 500MB video to the iPad/iPhone from a hard drive that is on my home network or on my Airport Extreme's hard drive, then I wouldn't want the 500MB to occupy space on the Macbook Air after the video is transferred.

Comment: So you want an alternative to iTunes to sync content to an iOS 8 device? (or is it that you aren't seeing the "trust this computer" dialog?

Comment: You could probably setup iCloud and have the videos sync the way you want to multiple devices.

Comment: actually, iTunes will be fine, but alternatives are ok too.  I just want to transfer using my Macbook Pro instead of my Macbook Air... I think clicking "Trust this computer" won't work, as it may only allow you to tie one iPad to 1 computer

Comment: iCloud might work but I only have 5GB space of iCloud and I don't want to pay for now... say if I want to transfer 10GB or 25GB or 28GB of video then I have to pay accordingly?